# Using Playwright for Python, how do I select (or find) an element?

Tags: python, webautomation, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to learn the Python version of Playwright. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python#documentation)

I would like to learn how to locate an element, so that I can do
things with it. Like printing the inner HTML, clicking on it and such.

The example below loads a page and prints the HTML

```
from playwright import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.newPage()
    page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/')
    print(page.innerHTML("*"))
    browser.close()
```

This page contains an element

```
<div class="user-agent">
    <p class="intro-text">Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4238.0 Safari/537.36</p>
</div>
```

Using Selenium, I could locate the element and print it's content like this

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("user-agent")
print(elem)
print(elem.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

How can I do the same in Playwright?

#UPDATE# - Note if you want to run this in 2021+ that current versions of playwright have changed the syntax from CamelCase to snake_case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `querySelector` function, and then call the `innerHTML` function:

```py
handle = page.querySelector(".user-agent")
print(handle.innerHTML())
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'querySelector'`

Comment: In Python, it would be `page.query_selector(".user-agent)`

Comment: Note that playwright for python has changed the syntax from `querySelector` to `query_selector` for the newer versions... If you find other older, no-longer-working playwright answers, this is probably why.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer does not work with the newer versions of Playwright. (Thanks @576i for pointing this out)

Here is the Python code that works with the newer versions (tested with version 1.5):

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/')
    ua = page.query_selector(".user-agent");
    print(ua.inner_html())
    browser.close()
```

To get only the text, use the `inner_text()` function.

```
print(ua.inner_text())
```

Comment: At the time of writing the question, the accepted answer was working Python code. 
Since then, playwright has changed a bit and now uses a more Python friendly notation. (This is the case for many other older playwright questions)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I am editing this answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

according to **Latest official** [python version Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/), you should use:

- [page](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page)'s [query_selector](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#pagequery_selectorselector)
- and [element](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle)'s [inner_html](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element_handleinner_html)

-> the code:

```py
# userAgentSelector = ".user-agent"
userAgentSelector = "div.user-agent"
elementHandle = page.query_selector(userAgentSelector)
uaHtml = elementHandle.inner_html()
print("uaHtml=%s" % uaHtml)
```

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers are a bit outdated. Nowadays the [locator API](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators) is recommended since auto-waiting is the common case:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.37.0

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.example.com")
    text = page.locator("h1").text_content()
    print(text)
    browser.close()
```

Use `query_selector` when you don't want to wait and instead want an immediate `None` if the element isn't visible.

<sub>Note that http://whatsmyuseragent.org is down, so I used a different site, but it's basically the same.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the solutions in the following article.
[Playwright >> Find, Locate, Select Elements/Tags using Playwright](https://thats-it-code.com/playwright/playwright__find-locate-search-elements-tags/)

- Playwright find all elements/tags containing specified text
- Playwright find elements/tags containing specified child element/tag
- Playwright loop through all elements/tags in locator() result
- Playwright find/get first element Playwright find/get last element
- Playwright get the parent element Playwright get the child element
- Playwright get nth child element Playwright find elements/tags by css
- class Playwright find elements near the specified text Playwright
- find elements/tags by attribute Playwright find elements/tags by id