# Using Playwright for Python, how do I select an option from a drop down list?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

This is a followup to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303326/using-playwright-for-python-how-do-i-select-or-find-an-element) on the basic functionality of Playwright for Python.

How do I **select** an **option** from a **drop down list**?

This example remote controls a vuejs-webseite that has a drop down list of fruits like "Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Orange"

Here I want to select the option "Banana"

```
from playwright import sync_playwright
import time

URL = '<my url>'

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.newPage()
    page.goto(URL)

    # identify this element by ID. Wait for it first
    new_selector = 'id=name-fruit'
    page.waitForSelector(new_selector)
    handle = page.querySelector(new_selector)

    # at this point I have the element and can print the content
    print(handle.innerHTML())
```

The drop down list HTML like this

```
<select data-v-c2cef47a="" id="name-fruit" autocomplete="true" class="form-select__select">
    <option data-v-c2cef47a="" disabled="disabled" value=""><!----></option>
    <option data-v-c2cef47a="" value="[object Object]"> Apple </option>
    <option data-v-c2cef47a="" value="[object Object]"> Banana </option>
    <option data-v-c2cef47a="" value="[object Object]"> Carrot </option>
    <option data-v-c2cef47a="" value="[object Object]"> Orange </option> 
</select>
```

in Selenium, I would select an option like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
Select(handle).select_by_visible_text('Banana')  # Note: no spaces needed!
```

The Javascript docs for Playwright have this, which is not exactly the same, because it seems to identify the object at the same time.

```
// Single selection matching the label
await page.selectOption('select#colors', { label: 'Blue' });
```

How do I do the selection in Playwright for Python?

I tried both of these and nothing happens.

```
handle.selectOption("text=Banana") 
handle.selectOption("text= Banana ")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying many different variants,
I guessed a working syntax

```
handle.selectOption({"label": "Banana"})
```

Comment: For future visitors, the syntax would now be `ElementHandle.select_option(label="Banana")`.

Comment: the above comment and answer are deprecated, For future visitors, the syntax would now be ```ElementHandle.selectOption(label="Banana")```

Answer (score 4):

A working example for Playwright for Python:

```
page.select_option('select#colors', label='Banana')
```

or for JavaScript:

```
await page.selectOption('select#colors', { label: 'Banana' });
```

See [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/input#select-options) for further handling of how to interact with selectors and how to use it in different languages and scenarios like JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! However it looks like we cannot select multiple options from the list at the same time by providing multiple labels.

Answer (score 2):

You can also alternatively use the index or the value to select an option:

```
handle.selectOption([{'label': 'Banana'}])  # selects 'Banana'
handle.selectOption([{'index': 3}])         # selects 'Carrot'
handle.selectOption([{'value': ''}])        # selects the empty option (works even though it is disabled)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the handle, you can use the page or frame directly.

Using playwright-python:

```py
page.select_option('select#name-fruit', label='Banana')
page.select_option('select#name-fruit', value='')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to select a list option based on "contains" , here is what I used

- Basically get a locator to find the option with text
- Get the full text of the option
- Use that full text to select the option

  ```
    dropdown_locator = page.locator(DROPDOWN_LOCATOR)
    dropdown_locator = dropdown_locator.filter(has_text="Banana")
    options_txt = activity_locator.text_content()
    options = options_txt.split('\n')
    print("Monkey searching banana in " + str(options))
    full_label = ""
    for item in options:
        if "Banana" in item:
            full_label = item.strip()
    print(full_label)

    if len(full_label) != 0:
        page.select_option(DROPDOWN_LOCATOR, label=full_label)
  ```